# Using the value of where clause to fire a function

Tags: laravel, where-clause

In laravel I want to display recipes with different status: 1 and 9. If the user is not logged in, only recipes with status 1 will be displayed.

No problem, this is done by:

```
return Recipe::where('published', 1)
            ->with('user')
            ->with('tagged')
            ->orderByDesc('id')
            ->paginate(10);
```

If the user is logged in, all recipes with status 1 and his own recipes with status 9 will be display.

Again, no problem, done by:

```
return Recipe::where('published', 1)
            ->orWhere(function ($query) {
                $query->where('published', '=', 9)
                    ->where('user_id', '=', auth()->id());
            })
            ->with('user')
            ->with('tagged')
            ->orderByDesc('id')
            ->paginate(10);
```

Furthermore if a recipes has status 9 and it belongs to a favorited user it should be also visible.

And this is where I am stuck. I look for something like:

```
return Recipe::where('published', 1)
            ->orWhere(function ($query) {
                $query->where('published', '=', 9)
                    ->where('user_id', '=', auth()->id())
                    ->orWhere('user_id', '=', User::find(###VALUEOFUSERID###)->isFavoritedByID(Auth::user()));
            })
            ->with('user')
            ->with('tagged')
            ->orderByDesc('id')
            ->paginate(10);
```

User::find(###VALUEOFUSERID###)->isFavoritedByID(Auth::user()) -> delivers the id of the user, if the user is favorited.

How can I get ###VALUEOFUSERID### in the where clause and fire the function to check if recipe with status 9 belongs to a favorited user?

Thanks! Looking forward to some ideas!

Comment: If I understand, a user has some favorited users right? If that's the case, then you could iterate over all the user's favorited users and put the id of it in there. You could create a function in your user model called something like: `getFavoritedUsers()` that would return a list of all the favorited users and then iterate over it.

Comment: @ettdro: thank you for your answer, but it's not exactly what I am looking for. I will iterate over all recipes, and if one of the recipe has status 9 and is from a favorited user, then it should be displayed. Iterating over all favorited users is not what I am looking for.